# chart but no database when using d3js

Tags: d3.js

Yesterday I created two charts in one page using d3.js. The question is - the page just shows one database of one chart, the other chart doesn't have any database, but it displayed an x-axis and y-axis.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? 
Thanks a lot.

Here gives my code:

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%H-%M-%S");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxi = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxi = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date1); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close1); });

var svg = d3.select("#e1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("01.tsv", type, function(error, data1) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) { return d.date1; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) { return d.close1; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxi);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxi)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data1)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

function type(d) {
  d.date1 = formatDate.parse(d.date1);
  d.close1 = +d.close1;
  return d;
}




var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var svg1 = d3.select("#e2").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("02.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg1.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

here gives my 01.tsv file:

date1      close1
06-30-00    93.24
06-31-00    95.35
06-32-00    98.84
06-33-00    99.92
06-34-00    99.80
06-35-00    99.47
06-36-00    100.39
06-37-00    100.40
06-38-00    100.81
06-39-00    103.92
06-40-00    105.06
06-41-00    106.88
06-42-00    107.34
06-43-00    108.74
06-44-00    109.36
06-45-00    107.52
06-46-00    107.34
06-47-00    109.44
06-48-00    110.02
06-49-00    111.98
06-50-00    113.54
06-51-00    112.89
06-52-00    110.69
06-53-00    113.62

here is my 02.tsv file :

letter  frequency
A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02782
D   .04253
E   .12702

Comment: It sounds like data issue, check if data is being read by both your `d3.tsv("02.tsv",..` data readers

Comment: thanks for your reply, if the reason is caused by  d3.tsv,then how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the tsv files ? So that we have an exact replica of your code.

Comment: sure,i hava uploaded the two tsv files below script code.

Comment: updated my answer. It was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with repetition of the variable/function names. I have attached a working copy.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%H-%M-%S");

var x1 = d3.time.scale()
 .range([0, width]);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxi1 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x1)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxi1 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y1)
.orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { 
    return x1(d.date1); })
.y(function(d) { 
    //console.log(y1(d.close1));
    return y1(d.close1); });

var svg = d3.select("#e1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +    ")");

d3.tsv("01.tsv", type1, function(error, data1) {
if (error) throw error; 
 x1.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) { return d.date1; }));
 y1.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) { return d.close1; }));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxi1);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxi1)
 .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

 svg.append("path")
  .datum(data1)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
 });

function type1(d) {
 d.date1 = formatDate.parse(d.date1);
 d.close1 = +d.close1;
 return d;
}




var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
 .orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left")
 .ticks(10, "%");

var svg1 = d3.select("#e2").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +     ")");

 d3.tsv("02.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
 if (error) throw error;
 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

 svg1.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

  svg1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", 6)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Frequency");

  svg1.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(data)
 .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
   .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
  });

 function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply,i tried to rename the type(d) with type1(d1),but it doesn't work as well.